# udp communication between two android devices: how to response

Tags: java, android, udp

I'm working on app, which would allow to users to communicate with each other if they're connected to the same network.
I've udp_server class and sendMessage client method.
Problem is when client send message to server (sendMessage method), server correctly read it, but when server send reply, the Toast with message sended is showing - it means that respone was send, but client don't recive it. try catc block also don't catch any exception.

udp_server class:

```
private class MyDatagramReceiver extends Thread {
        private boolean bKeepRunning = true;
        private String lastMessage = "";

        public void run() {
            String message;
            byte[] lmessage = new byte[1024*512];
            final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(lmessage, lmessage.length);
            try {
                final DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(11234);
                while(bKeepRunning) {
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    message = new String(lmessage, 0, packet.getLength());
                    lastMessage = message;
                    runOnUiThread(updateTextMessage);

                    byte[] response = "response".getBytes();
                    final DatagramPacket response_packet = new DatagramPacket(response,response.length,InetAddress.getByName("192.168.8.111"),11234);
                    socket.send(response_packet);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sended",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (final Throwable e) {                 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void kill() {
            bKeepRunning = false;
        }
        public String getLastMessage() {
            return lastMessage;
        }
    }

    private Runnable updateTextMessage = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"recived",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (myDatagramReceiver == null) return;
                adapter.add(myDatagramReceiver.getLastMessage());
        }
    }
```

client send messge method:

```
 private void sendMessage(final String message) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            String stringData;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DatagramSocket ds = null;
                try {
                    ds = new DatagramSocket();                      
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.8.188");
                    DatagramPacket dp;
                    dp = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.length(), serverAddr, 11234);
                    ds.send(dp);
                    byte[] lMsg = new byte[1000];
                    dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
                    ds.receive(dp);
                    stringData = new String(lMsg, 0, dp.getLength());

                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                      
                } finally {
                    if (ds != null) {
                        ds.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

Is there anyone who know what's happening there?

Resolved:
I put the recive part of code in sendMessage method into while loop, like that:

```
boolean keepWaiting = true;
while(keepWaiting) {
    ds.receive(packet);
    stringData = new String(lMsg, 0, packet.getLength());
    runOnUiThread(respone); //there I analize response
    keepWaiting = false;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any way of monitoring network traffic (i.e. wireshark) so you can verify these packets are both being sent to and received by the respective devices?

Comment: no, but I can download it.